# javascript: smallest code to convert seconds to time

Tags: code-golf, string, arithmetic, javascript

Given seconds like 11728, write the smallest javascript function that returns a string like `3hrs. 15min. 28sec.`

`signature textTime([int] t,[bool] z,[bool] m)`

`t` is the time like 11728 and you can assume `int`
`z` is optional and true means drop zero times, so `3hrs. 0min. 28sec.` becomes `3hrs. 28sec.`
`m` is optional and true means show only up to minutes, so `3hrs. 16min. 48sec.` is `3hrs. 16min.`

For 1 hour, `1hrs.` is fine (vs `1hr.`)

Example:

```
textTime(11728) returns "3hrs. 0min. 28sec."
textTime(11728,true) returns "3hrs. 28sec."
textTime(11728,true,true) returns "3hrs."
```

Regex is fine, speed is inconsequential.

**Shortest code wins.**

Comment: Your function parameters don't make any sense.

Comment: What about days, weeks, months and years? Examples don't make a specification.

Comment: this is not "date time", but a measure of hours and minutes and seconds.  1 day is not exactly 24hours and 0 secs, so a lot of things are measured in hours, which is the highest level measure of "real" time

Comment: I apologize for using [brackets] to state the var type, which made it look like an array.  maybe [int] t  would have been better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CA6GM/2/ "Javascript 120"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Javascript,  <del>194</del>  192

```
function T(a,c,e){d=60;s=["sec","min","hrs"];alert(t=[a,(0|a/d)*d,(0|a/d/d)*d*d].map(function(a,b,f){p=(a-(0|f[b+1]))/Math.pow(d,b);return e&&1>b?"":c&&!p?"":p+s[b]+". "}).reverse().join(""))}
```

Run it e.g. with

`T(7215,true,false) //2hrs. 15sec.`

*Could probably be golfed a bit more*
<sub>Edit Notes:

Added function name for the cost of 1 character*
Renamed the function to `T`. I'm assigning `t` in the function hence i was overwriting the function itself.
Changed (a/(d*d)) -> (a/d/d)</sub>

Comment: Excellent!, it works in all cases.  I'm marking this as the winner because it's current standard javascript.

Comment: `t(3600, true)` gives *TypeError: string is not a function*. Also, `a/(d*d)` → `a/d/d` and `a-(0|f[b+1])` → `0|a-f[b+1]`.

Comment: @minitech Thanks! I don't know how i missed the *d/d*. `1.` Only the second time, called. I was overriding `t` `2.`Changed it. `3.` This is not quite correct. I'm needing the first one. as I'm accessing `f[b+1]` which can be `undefined` when exceeding the arrays range.`2-(0|undefined /*0*/) //2` wheras `0|(2-undefined /*NaN*/) //0`

Comment: Oh, in that case, try `~~f[b+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

<s>155</s> 147 characters.

```
textTime=(t,z,m,x)=>(x=[t/3600,t/60%60,t%60].map((t,i)=>(!z||t|0)&&~~t+["hrs","min","sec"][i]+"."||0).slice(0,2+!m),(z?x.filter(x=>x):x).join(" "))
```

If the parameters made a little more sense, yes, it would be fewer.

Non-ES6, changing the name and using globals like @C5H8NNaO4 did, at 183 characters:

```
function t(t,z,m){return(x=[t/3600,t/60%60,t%60].map(function(t,i){return(!z||t|0)&&~~t+["hrs","min","sec"][i]+"."||0}).slice(0,2+!m),(z?x.filter(function(x){return x}):x).join(" "))}
```

Comment: How do i run it ?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: The latest Firefox.

Comment: those are like c# lamdas right?  are they (will they be) standard javascript?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing: Yes, they’re part of ES6, the next/“current” standard. You can already use them in Firefox. In other browsers, it’s `function t(t,z,m,x){return x=(m?[t/60,t%60]:[t/3600,t/60%60,t%60]).map(function(t,i){return(!z||t|0)&&~~t+["sec","min","hrs"][2-i-~~m]+"."||0}),(z?x.filter(function(x){return x;}):x).join(" ")}` (193).

Comment: I got SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL when I just pasted this version into chrome (the console)

Comment: @AwokeKnowing: Copying that adds some silly carriage returns or something. I’ll add it to the answer.

Comment: `t(3600,1,1) //"60min."` shouldn't that be `"1hrs."`?

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4: Ah, yes, there were more details added to the question. I originally interpreted “show up to minutes” as “show minutes and seconds”, not “show hours and minutes”. Give me a minute…

Answer (score 1):

## 165 chars

```
function x(T, Z, M){
f=Math.round;h=T/3600;m=h%1*60;s=m%1*60;
r=f(h)+'hrs '+f(m)+'min '+f(s)+'sec'
Z?r=r.replace(/0\w+/g,''):0
M?r=r.replace(/\d+sec/,''):0
return r}
```

I just realized that this solution doesn't work for T<60, so I added a few characters and that fixed it (see below):

### 167 chars

```
function x(T, Z, M){
f=Math.round;h=T/3600;m=h%1*60;s=m%1*60;
r=f(h)+'hrs '+f(~~m)+'min '+f(s)+'sec'
Z?r=r.replace(/0\w+/g,''):0
M?r=r.replace(/\d+sec/,''):0
return r}
```

If you don't care about getting the rounding quite right:

### 149 chars

```
function x(T, Z, M){
h=T/3600;m=h%1*60;s=m%1*60;
r=~~h+'hrs '+~~m+'min '+~~s+'sec'
Z?r=r.replace(/0\w+/g,''):0
M?r=r.replace(/\d+sec/,''):0
return r}
```

Comment: Dat modulus though.. amazing!